# SQLITE: Replacing highly redundant with index to another table

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I have a table `t` with around 500,000 rows. One of the columns (`stringtext`) contains a very long string and I have now discovered that that there are in fact only 80 distinct strings. I'd like to declutter table `t` by moving the strings into a separate table, `s`, and merely referencing them in `t`.

I have created a separate table of the long strings, including what is effectively an explicit row-index number using:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stmp AS
  SELECT DISTINCT
    stringtext
  FROM t;
CREATE TABLE s AS
  SELECT _ROWID_ AS stringindex, stringtext
  FROM stmp;
```

(It was creating this table that showed me there were only a few distinct strings).

How can I now replace stringtext in `t` with the corresponding stringindex from `s`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think about something like `Update t set stringtext = (select stringindex from s where s.stringtext = t.stringtext)` and would recommend first making an index on `s(stringtext)` as SQLite might not be smart enough to build a temporary index. And then a VACUUMing would be in order.

Untested.

Comment: Thank you. I used your advice but did something slightly different so that I could end up with a column called `stringindex` in table `t`, instead of simply refilling `t.stringtext` with the `s.stringindex` values. Creating the index on `s.stringtext` manually did indeed speed things up, by around 10%; not significant in my case, but it could be. `VACUUM`ing reduced the database to 40% of the original. All worth while. The database is a fixed resource for some statistical analyses and won't be subsequently altered, so the relative cost of creation is very small. Thanks again.